# how to test onchange event for a text field in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to test a reactJS application where all the textbox in login.js have some onChange event. 
Using .sendKeys(), i am able to pass the value, but after clicking login button, those onChange events are not triggered.
I have tried with tab, enter as well as .click() and .clear() method. They are not working. Please help!

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example to your question.

Comment: Post your code to better verify the source of the problem

Comment: what happens when you try it manually ?

Comment: IF not working, What is an Exception